# HashiCorp Vault + node-vault + write = 404

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm trying a simple operation using node-vault but it is not working. Here is my attempt:

1. Configuration

   ```
    var options = {
      apiVersion: 'v2', // default
      endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8200', // default
    };

    // get new instance of the client
    var vault = require("node-vault")(options);
    vault.token = "<<MY TOKEN>>";
   ```
2. Usage

   ```
    vault.write('secret/data/new', {"data": {"foo": "bar"}}).then(
          function (value: any) {
            console.log(value);
          })
          .catch((err: any) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
   ```
3. Response

   ```
    { statusCode: 404, body: { errors: [] } }
   ```

But, if I run `vault kv put secret/data/new foo=bar` it does work and value is there.

What is going on?

Thank you all and I wish a happy new year!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here is what I did.

1. Reinstall Vault, something happened to storage because I did a lot of attempts and commands in it.
2. Enable secrets engine in specific path `vault secrets enable -path=testPath kv`
3. Write to this path

Configure:

```
    export const VAULT_OPTIONS = {
      apiVersion: 'v1',
      endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8200',
      token: '<<YOUR TOKEN>>'
    };
    vault = require("node-vault")(VAULT_OPTIONS);
```

Write:

```
    this.vault.write('test/data/mykey', {"data": {"tests": {"test1": "test1-value", "test2": "test2-value"}}}).then(
          (result: any) => {
            console.log(res.data);
          }, (error: any) => {
              console.log(error);
          });
```

Please note that `path` must contain `data` and data must be surounded by `data` ({ data: {key:value}) as well.